# embed air in flex mobile application?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, flex4.5

I'm quite new to developing in Flex. I've found out that it's possible to create mobile applications with Flex 4.5. So far so good, I've made an app and it's working well on my mobile phone. But there is one thing that I'm not very happy with. When I'm installing the app I also have to install Adobe Air (stand alone application). So is not realy cool and not the way to go in my opinion because this will look strange to the users of the app. And especially the users which aren't realy 'geek minded'.

Any solutions to this? Is it possible to include or embed Air in the app? It will make the filesize of the app bigger but that's a much smaller problem then having to install a complete different app next to the real app.

All the best from NL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called Captive Runtime and was introduced in AIR 3.

To use it today, you'll have to overlay the AIR 3 SDK onto the Flex Framework of your choice (I suggest 4.5.1).  Then you'll have to use command line tools to compile your app using captive runtime.

This will most likely be a lot easier when Flash Builder 4.6 rolls around.

[More information](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html)